# How to give max-width property to a list element with viewport padding

Tags: css

I have set viewport padding to the li items in my div. I want the li elements to stop expanding after 1025px. But setting max width doesnt seem to work.Please help

```
             .header_topics > ul> li> a{
                   padding : 5vw 2vw 5vw 2vw;

              }






              <div class="header_topics">

                        <ul  style="display:flex;justify-content:center;max-width:1025px;width:100%;background:green">
                                    <li ><a href= "{% url 'home' %}" target="_self" > <span style="max-width:1025px">Home</span></a></li>
                                    <li ><a href="{% url 'about' %}" target="_self"  ><span style="max-width:1025px;color:#a4a6a8;border:none"> About</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" ><span style="max-width:1025px">Products</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#"><span style="max-width:1025px">Solutions</span></a></li>
                                    <li s><a href="{% url 'support' %}" target="_self"  ><span style="max-width:1025px" >Support</span></a></li>
                                </ul>


                    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that at window width of 1025 px the menu should no longer get wider?

Comment: yes , exactly  thats what I mean

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;` will include the padding in the overall width of the list items

Comment: where should I put box-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This menu will stop getting wider after a window size of 1025px (Assuming that `.header-topics`'s width is the window's width.

When you set the li `max-width` property, you are saying that each menu item has the max width of 1025px, when really you intended to limit the menu's width. Hope it helps.

```css
.header_topics {
  max-width: 1025px;
}

.header_topics li {
  padding: 5vw 2vw;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .header_topics li {
    // your fixed padding here
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_topics">
  <ul  style="display:flex;justify-content:center;width:100%;background:green">
    <li><a href= "{% url 'home' %}" target="_self" > <span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}" target="_self"  ><span style="color:#a4a6a8;border:none"> About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ><span>Products</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Solutions</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'support' %}" target="_self"  ><span>Support</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you didnt put padding to li elements. The problem is li elements keep getting far apart

Comment: no , span style has to be removed. is there a way to get current padding of the li item through js and make it fixed after 1025

Comment: Now you can set a fixed width after a screen size of 1025px

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But your solution worked. I put fixed padding after 1024px. Thank you so much for your time